# “Bitter. Sweet. Alive.” vs. “Bitter, sweet, alive.”

Tags: punctuation, commas, lists, periods

Here is a quote by Joanne Harris:

> Happiness. Simple as a glass of chocolate or tortuous as the heart. Bitter. Sweet. Alive.

Shouldn’t there be commas instead of full stops in the list at the end, i.e. as follows?

> Happiness. Simple as a glass of chocolate or tortuous as the heart. Bitter, sweet, alive.

Comment: No, it would lose the effect meant by the author.

Comment: There are times when punctuation can affect the meaning of a sentence. Other than that, it is just a matter of style.

Comment: What @Mick said. Style.

Answer (score 1):

In a formal document such as an academic paper or business letter, this punctuation would not be appropriate. But in a piece of writing meant to convey emotion, this "incorrect" punctuation is deliberately used for emphasis.